# loop to update data coming from form php mysql html

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following code that I created to update the database with the data coming from a a php form. `$_POST['variables']` are different arrays.
the issue I am having is when I echo `$updater` the field status and the field display values are not in the correct order.  for example if I check the checkbox 3. it will return the value enabled on the first line of the results. any suggestions would help thank you

```
//update data

$priority = $_POST['priority']; // this will be an array
$enable = $_POST['enable'];
$height = $_POST['height'];
$position = $_POST['position'];
$widgetid = $_POST['widgetid'];
$display = $_POST['display'];

$i = -1;
foreach($priority as $priori)
{
    ++$i;
    $row_enable = $enable[$i];
    $row_height = $height[$i];
    $row_prio   = $priority[$i];
    $positio    = $position[$i];
    $disp       = $display[$i];
    $widgeti    = $widgetid[$i];

    if (isset($enable[$i]))
         $enables ="y";
    else
         $enables ="n";

    if (isset($display[$i]))
         $displ = "y"; 
    else 
         $displ = "n";

    //DO THIS FOR THE REST AND THEN YOUR UPDATE QUERY
    $updater = "UPDATE hpoptions SET position='$positio', height='$row_height', status='$enables', display='$displ', priority='$row_prio' WHERE userid='$ud' and widgetid='$widgeti'";

    echo $updater."<br>";

} // ends here
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee you will get your arrays in the desired order, unless you force it in the HTML. You probably have something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="position[]"> 
<input type="text" name="height[]"> ...
<input type="hidden" name="widgetid[]" value="w1">
  ...
<input type="text" name="position[]">
<input type="text" name="height[]"> ...
<input type="hidden" name="widgetid[]" value="w2">
  ...
```

You need to add an extra dimension to the arrays encoded on the field name. You need an unique id for each field group, and I believe your `widgetid` is exactly that, right? So you can do:

```
<input type="text" name="data[w1][position]"> 
<input type="text" name="data[w1][height]"> ...
 ...
<input type="text" name="data[w2][position]"> 
<input type="text" name="data[w2][height]"> ...
 ...
```

Notice you don't even need a field called `widgetid` anymore, since the ids will be encoded on every field name. In PHP, you do this to loop through the results:

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $widgetid => $data) {
    // Make sure to check if the values won't make your SQL query vulnerable to injection!
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain
    $widgetid = mysql_real_escape_string($widgetid);
    $position = is_numeric($data['position']) ? $data['position'] : 0;
    // ...
    // Build your update query here
}
```

Comment: thanks Im trying it now. the form fields are generate from mysql ... I cant name them w1 w2 etc...

Comment: Use aliases so you can name them.

Comment: @JoseAdrian not sure what you mean by aliases

Comment: Can you print the $updater var and put it in your question? Also your Your form, if possible provide a link.

Comment: It should be working. Try [this code](http://codepad.org/zCDYfpNy) on your local server as a proof of concept

Comment: He is suggesting to do that. Read his answer carefully.

Comment: @bfavaretto  ($_POST['data'] as $widgetid => $data) whats $widgetid? you asked me to remove the hidden field widgetid[] ...

Comment: I did read it very carefully and tried it now its not returning any results

Comment: print_r returns nothing as well

Comment: @fogsy, your screenshot shows you're passing values like "w1" and "w2" to the update query, on column `widgetid`.

Comment: yes. those are different they come from $row['widgetid'], im not passing them thats where the update is made. its based of userid AND widgetid

Comment: thanks for all your help bfavaretto ... its still not working but I appreciate all the efforts!!thank you